# Firebase Transaction Not Updating / Returns Null

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use a Firebase Transaction in JavaScript. For some reason it completely stopped working and updating. It had worked a few hours ago, but perhaps I accidentally changed some code to make it not work. Any ideas on why the transaction is not updating?

```
function paymentSubmit() {
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var email = user.email;
  var parking_location = document.getElementById('parking_location_input').value;
  var price = document.getElementById('price_input').value;

  firebaseRef.child("Parking Lots").child(parking_location).transaction(function (lot) {
    if (lot) {
      console.log(lot);
      if (lot.admin == email) {
        lot.price = price;
      }
    }
    return lot;
  },
    function (error, committed, snapshot) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Transaction failed abnormally!', error);
      } else if (!committed) {
        console.log('We aborted the transaction.');
      } else {
        console.log('Lot updated!');
      }
    }).then(function (snapshot) {
      console.log('Transaction successfully committed!');
      firebaseRef.child("Parking Lots").child(parking_location).set({
        "price": snapshot.price,
        "admin": snapshot.admin
      });
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Transaction failed: ', error);
    });
  clearForm();
}
```

[image: Database]

Comment: It seems like you are storing prices as a string, not as a long. But besides that to understand your situation completely and to help you we need you to show us the logs.

Comment: console.log(lot) returns null. There are no errors or anything.

Comment: If the logs after the transaction is completed are null as well, then I'd advise you to verify parking_location variable's validity

Comment: Yes the variable parking_location is correct

Comment: I see that you have used white space in your database directory. I'm not sure if Firebase supports that. Could you run a test where you've changed "Parking Lots" to "parking_lots"?

Comment: @Mustafa You can use spaces in Firebase keys. From the docs:  *If you create your own keys, they must be UTF-8 encoded, can be a maximum of 768 bytes, and cannot contain ., $, #, [, ], /, or ASCII control characters 0-31 or 127. You cannot use ASCII control characters in the values themselves, either.* Space is ASCII 32

Comment: For some reason it works if I put a window.alert message at the end. If I take that out, no transactions happen. Any ideas why?